# Вывод значений цикла в строке

Tags: php

Как внутри echo в div блок передать значение переменной "a", чтобы выводилось с 1 до 9.
А у меня вместо цифр выводится просто $a

```js
<?php 

$a = 1;

for ($a = 1; $a < 10; $a++) { 

echo '<div class="xopa">  a равно = $a  </div>'; 

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вы не изучили тему: чем отличаются двойные кавычки от одинарных. Ознакомьтесь: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single  (со слова "Замечание") и https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double  (со слов "Но самым важным свойством...")

В данном случае проще поменять кавычки: одинарные на двойные, а двойные на одинарные

Comment: Если внутри div будут значения из php, то лучше использовать двойные кавычки, верно? При этом в class нужно будет заменить двойные кавычки на одинарные?

Comment: А переменная "a" это специальный символ?

Comment: @ЧелМедведоСвин  добавил ссылку ещё одну в ответ......... если переменные внутри строки - да, либо использовать двойные кавычки, либо конкатенацию............ также прочитайте раздел про строки до самого конца, там внизу написано много примеров вставки данных в строки